# NUnit: "Fixture" -?

Tags: .net, nunit

Sorry for my English.

I am learn NUnit documentation ([v 2.6](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=actionAttributes&r=2.6)), and translate it for russian language ([here](http://nunit26.ildasm.com/)). I can't correctly translate it:

> The Assert.Ignore method provides you with the ability to dynamically cause a test or suite to be ignored at runtime. It may be called in a test, setup or **fixture** setup method.

and

> Fixture - an object representing the user **fixture**, if available, or null

"Fixture"... This word turns the translated result into the senseless. :((( 
Probably I incorrectly translate it. What synonym on sense for the "Fixture" word? There can be a "class"?

Regards

Comment: Maybe this: [Test fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture). There's also http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixture , but it doesn't look helpful.

Comment: *Fixture* is a _class_ that contains tests and, optionally, setup or teardown methods. [link](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.6) Anyway, I'll advice you to start learning nUnit with following [article on russian](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/sergeypopov/4936/)

Comment: Non-native English speaker here: as far as I get it, a fixture (in the general way) is something that holds an object in order to let it be inspected or modified ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixture): _"a device for supporting work during machining"_). This can be "translated" to the class that is holding and inspecting the thing you want to test. When I click around a bit in Wikipedia, it brings me to the German [Spannzeug](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spannzeug) page. Perhaps from this view you can find a fitting Russian translation? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [TestFixture] decorator just means that your class contains test code.

So in answer to your question; the "fixture" that is being referred to is the class containing your unit tests.

Looking at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.6.2 we have:

> The first thing to notice about this class is that it has a
>   [TestFixture] attribute associated with it – this is the way to
>   indicate that the class contains test code (this attribute can be
>   inherited). The class has to be public and there are no restrictions
>   on its superclass. The class also has to have a default constructor.

Hope this helps :)